How does the "Piranha PDVT 1609" voltage detector sense DC voltage?
Recently, in my house repair
an electrician used single terminal device "Piranha PDVT 1609".
It was not only detecting AC but also but also DC for example 12V DC.
It's a single terminal device that can detect voltage with contact and current without contact. It may be somehow understandable that it can detect AC voltage like an analog control pen but what I can't understand is how it can not only senses but gives the magnitude of the DC like 12V 24V etc. As far as I know fully isolated DC voltage (potential difference) cannot be detected by only a single terminal contact. as an unexperienced EEE student I have just felt that I have been tricked.
So I was only able to test my 12V DC adapter and it has been correctly detected that 12V on positive pole. So is the negative pole of 12V DC connected to Earth terminal so that the circuit gets completed through my body to the earth or any other explanations? I couldn't test any battery but I still don't believe that it can detect any 12V battery just by connecting it to the positive pole of it while leaving negative pole open or vice versa.
I have searched for a datasheet but I couln't find anything.

Here's a YouTube video here in what YouTube thinks is Turkish. I got it to closed captions in English. These included the lovely, "there is an apricot on the back", "there is a cigar on the tip" and "55 goals are sweet". (We're not quite there yet with this stuff.)
I'd recommend that you trust your instinct. It's probably detecting electric field and whether or not it's alternating and then guessing the voltage.
